# Building a Docker Image with the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin and Colima

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, docker-daemon, colima

I'm trying to create a docker image of a Spring Boot application using the Gradle plugin. I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.4 and Gradle 7.1.1.

I'm on a Mac, and I don't have Docker Desktop installed. Indeed, I run docker using Colima.

The problem is that I cannot build the docker image with the command `./gradlew bootBuildImage` since Gradle cannot find the docker daemon:

```
Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "[2] No such file or directory"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible
```

Is there any configuration I have to do in Colima or my `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Do you have a `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set, or a `docker.host` configured in the build plugin configuration as shown in the docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.docker-daemon)? Without this, the plugin should try to connect to the container runtime using the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket, which seems like it should work from a quick read of the Colima docs.

Comment: I tried this myself and got the same error as you without any Docker host configuration. I'll look into it and see what it will take to make this work.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottFrederick.  Hope to hear you soon!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colima creates a socket in the location `~/.colima/docker.sock` by default. Running the command `docker context ls` should show a context named `colima` with the socket location shown in the `DOCKER ENDPOINT` column.

You can configure the Spring Boot Gradle plugin to use this socket by setting the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to `unix:///Users/<user>/.colima/docker.sock` or by adding the following to your build file as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.docker-daemon).

```
tasks.named("bootBuildImage") {
  docker {
    host = "unix:///Users/<user>/.colima/docker.sock"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott. So, it's not possible to have a `build.gradle` file that is not dependent on the location of the `docker.sock` file. Did I understand right?

Comment: I've tested Spring Boot's image building with 4 container engines - Docker Engine, minikube, podman, and now colima. All expose the Docker client REST API using different means, as you can see in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.docker. It would be difficult for Spring Boot to guess from all these possibilities. The `docker` CLI uses the contexts mentioned above, but podman has it's own `podman` CLI that works differently so that's not entirely reliable either.

Comment: It is possible to have a `build.gradle` file that is independent of the socket location, as the Spring Boot plugins will honor the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable. For Colima, you can set this with a command like `export DOCKER_HOST=$(docker context inspect colima -f '{{.Endpoints.docker.Host}}')`.